# Running multiple cmd.exe processes from a batch file in Java

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd

I'm currently revising a small application that I wrote as a demonstration for a security course I'm taking.  The prof loved it and has requested some modifications that I'm unable to figure out.  I would like to add the ability to pass in as a parameter to the batch file a few variables from my code (i.e. the number of cmd.exe instances to run and in the code below, the message variable).

Using an answer found at [Launching multiple shell prompts from a single batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612181/launching-multiple-shell-prompts-from-a-single-batch-file) among other helpful SO threads, here's an example of the code I've put together:

The batch file:

```
@echo off

if not "%1" == "" goto :%1

SET message="The random number is: "

SET /a rand=%RANDOM%

start "Job 1" "%~dpfx0" job1
start "Job 2" "%~dpfx0" job2
start "Job 3" "%~dpfx0" job3
goto :eof

:job1
call :showMessage %message% %rand%

:job2
call :showMessage %message% %rand%

:job3
call :showMessage %message% %rand%

:showMessage 
echo %~1 %~2
```

This works great to spawn 3 instances of cmd.exe. I'm stumped, though, as to how I can dynamically choose the number of jobs to run and how to pass in a variable to the batch file with the above configuration.  I figure I need a FOR loop, but I'm uncertain how to do it either with the above setup or a new way entirely.

I'm 110% sure the line from the batch file "if not "%1" == "" goto :%1" is absolutely necessary as without it, the system will continuously open cmd.exe processes (experimentation resulted in several hard resets).  It interferes with passing in parameters to the batch file, but I am not able to find a way around using it.

For reference:

The batch file is executed in Java via the following code:

```
public class CmdProcess{
    Runtime rt;

    public cmdProcess() {
        rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    }

    public void startSpawning() {
        try {
            rt.exec("cmd.exe /C example.bat");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I call this class from the gui code with the following listener:

```
private void setupListeners() {
    class spawnButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            // Fire off 3 cmd.exe processes that show a message
            CmdProcess proc = new CmdProcess ();
            proc.startSpawning();
            // Increment the local counter and display on the client
            processCounter += 3;
            processCounterTextField.setText(Integer.toString(processCounter));
            }
        }
```

**tl;dr**: I need to know if it's possible with DOS magic in a batch file executed with Java to pass in the parameters necessary to run any number of cmd.exe instances that will each perform the same command.

***EDIT TO INCLUDE SOLUTION:***
Based on input from @JosefZ, here is a solution that works the way I need it to:

```
@echo off
if not %1 == "" (
    set /A noiter=%1
    ) Else (
    set /A noiter=1
    )

SET message="The random number is: "

SET /a rand=%RANDOM%

if %noiter% == 0 (
    call :showMessage %message% %rand%
    ) Else (
    For /L %%G IN (1, 1, %noiter%) do (
        start "Job %%G" "%~dpfx0" job%%G
        set /a rand=%RANDOM%
        :job%%G
        call :showMessage %message% %rand%
        )
    )
)

:showMessage
echo %~1 %~2
```

If I wanted to pass in additional parameters, I would handle them in the first if block...

```
@echo off
if not %1 == "" (
    rem passed in parameters
    set /A noiter=%1
    set /A message=%2
    set /A rand=%3
    ) Else (
    rem default parameters
    set /A noiter=1
    set message="The random number is: "
    set /a rand=%RANDOM%
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know we can call a script with a parameter. Let's check this parameter as follows: if it's a numeric value, consider this is instances count of `cmd.exe` to be launched and remember it to a numeric environment variable: `set /A "noiter=%1"`; otherwise it's simply a flag to end. Here's the code:

```
if not "%1" == "" (
  set /A "noiter=%1"
) Else (
  set /A "noiter=1"
)
```

Sample an effect of `set /A "noiter=text"` yoursef. Now we can test value of the `noiter` variable:

```
if "%noiter%" == "0" (
  call :showMessage %message% %rand%
) Else (
  rem loop here
)
```

Finally, substitute next code snippet in place of above's `rem loop here`:

```
  rem loop from 1 stepping 1 to "noiter"
  For /L %%G IN (1, 1, %noiter%) do (
    rem for testing purposes only: echo our command line first  
    echo start "Job %%G" "%~dpnx0" job%%G
    rem for testing purposes only: simulate real call
    set /a "rand=%RANDOM%"
    call :showMessage %message% %rand%
  )
```

This is a raw blueprint only; there are still some issues: e.g. `%random%` tends to stay constant :-)

So, learn more on [set command](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html), [setlocal](http://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html), [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) etc. etc.

Comment: It looks like there's a missing function for each job, i.e. :job%%G.  I'm going to experiment and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: All the `Job1`, `Job2` and `Job3` in your code seem to be identical: `call :showMessage %message% %rand%`. Should be different? Then you should appoint maximal count of cmds, create that number of labels and instead of `call :showMessage %message% %rand%` substitute `call :%1` or even (uncommendable) `goto :%1`

Comment: I've edited my original post with a solution that works for what I need based on the input you've provided.  TYVM for your knowledge and assistance, @JosefZ!